# How can I use percentages in a switch condition to represent player status based on health?

Tags: java

I should preface this by saying I'm VERY new to coding and Java in general; forgive my stupidity! I'm attempting to set up a status system for the player based on how much health they have, wherein their current Status is a String involved in a switch function which changes from "You are doing fine!" to "You are dying!". However, rather than doing it with single digits, I want to do it with percentage of health so the message does not change when they reach 50 or 25 percent health, whether the player has 50 or 10 health max.

Essentially, I want to make it so in place of single variables representing certain values of health in the switch function, percentages of PCHealth do. This is what I don't want, but what I know how to do:

```
int PCHealth = 10;
String Status = "";
switch (PCHealth) {
  case 5: Status = "You're fine!";
  case 2: Status = "You're dying!";
}
```

Here's what I want sketched out in fake code:

```
int PCHealth = 10;
String Status = "';
switch (PCHealth) {
  case [50% of PCHealth] = "You're fine!";
  case [20 % of PCHealth] = "You're dying!";
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: you can evaluate those values before switch and store it in a variable and then put that variable inside switch

Answer (score 1):

```
/*

Things that you will need to know
- integer division vs double
- type casting
- Math.ceil()

# int division

10/25 --> 0

# double division

10.0/25 --> 0.4

# Math.ceil()

Math.ceil(0.4) --> 1.0



0-25 XXX
25-50 fine
50-75 good
75-100 great

*/
```

---

Play with this code, printout things that you don't understand or what value they are holding... I tried to keep things simple.

```
public class MyClass {

    private static int maxHealth = 100;
    public static String getPlayerHealthStatus(double pHealth){

        String pHStatus = "";
        int pHealth_case = (int) Math.ceil( pHealth / (maxHealth / 4));

        switch (pHealth_case) {
            case 4:
                pHStatus = "You're doing great!"; 
                break;

            case 3:
                pHStatus = "You're doing good!";
                break;

            case 2:
                pHStatus = "You're fine!";
                break;

            case 1:
                pHStatus = "You're dying!";
                break;

            case 0:
                pHStatus = "You died!";
                break;

            default:
                pHStatus = "invalid player health";
        }

        return pHStatus;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int playerHealth = 90;
        System.out.println("player health: "+playerHealth+" status: "+getPlayerHealthStatus(playerHealth));

        playerHealth = 70;
        System.out.println("player health: "+playerHealth+" status: "+getPlayerHealthStatus(playerHealth));

        playerHealth = 40;
        System.out.println("player health: "+playerHealth+" status: "+getPlayerHealthStatus(playerHealth));

        playerHealth = 20;
        System.out.println("player health: "+playerHealth+" status: "+getPlayerHealthStatus(playerHealth));

        playerHealth = 0;
        System.out.println("player health: "+playerHealth+" status: "+getPlayerHealthStatus(playerHealth));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
player health: 90 status: You're doing great!
player health: 70 status: You're doing good!
player health: 40 status: You're fine!
player health: 20 status: You're dying!
player health: 0 status: You died!
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do it with `if-else`. Its very simple and good to understand.

```java
public String getStatus(int PChealth, int maxValue) {
    float percent = (PChealth * 1.0f) / maxValue;

    if (percent > 75) return "great";
    else if (percent > 50) return "mid";
    else if (percent > 25) return "not good";
    else if (PChealth == 0) return "dead";
    else return "bad";
}
```

Side notes: The first `if` that evalute `true` will return the correct value.
Savvy?

Answer (score 0):

I would store the max health in the variable `MaxHealth` then try the following switch! :)

Here we have `if` statement in the `switch` statement, that will do case 1 if the health is between 0 and 20% and so on

```
double PCHealth = __ ;

switch (((0 <= PCHealth && PCHealth <= (0.2 * MaxHealth)) ? 0 : 
        ((0.2 * MaxHealth) > PCHealth && (0.5 * MaxHealth) < PCHealth) ? 1 : 2)
  {

    case 0:
        Status = "You're dying!";
        break;
    case 1:
        Status = "You're fine!";
        break;
    case 2:
        Status = "You're doing excelent";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to have expressions in case statements, use `if-else` statements or like @Onkar said store them in a separate variable.

`if-else` should be cleaner for your use case.